# How to detect whether a CA used EV for a certificate using openssl

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I want to download the certificate of a particular hostname and detect whether the CA used EV (extended validation) when issuing it. So far I was not able to find anything that identifies certificates as being EV. Is there any way to achieve this? Ideally using OpenSSL?

Answer (score 9):

Note that EV certs are not structurally different — they are just a cert issued under a different policy. So you have to check the policy. (See [EV certs on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Extended_Validation_certificate_identification))

You will need to do a fairly extensive table lookup; it isn't native to openssl I'm afraid.

This is probably a duplicate of [How to check if a X509 certificate has "Extended Validation" switched on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705157/how-to-check-if-a-x509-certificate-has-extended-validation-switched-on)

In response to some comments below:

This attribute is in the "X509v3 extensions" field. [`x509v3_config(5)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/x509v3_config.html#Certificate-Policies) notes

> #### Certificate Policies.
>
> This is a raw extension. All the fields of this extension can be set by using the appropriate syntax.
>
> If you follow the PKIX recommendations and just using one OID then you just include the value of that OID. Multiple OIDs can be set separated by commas, for example:
>
> ```
> certificatePolicies= 1.2.4.5, 1.1.3.4
> ```

That's how they get *into* the cert.  Here is what it looks like in the cert: for example, if you examine the GlobalSign certificate protecting https://www.globalsign.com/en/ :

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect www.globalsign.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -ext certificatePolicies
```

This will show something like:

```
X509v3 Certificate Policies:                                                                                                               
    Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.1.1                                                                                                             
      CPS: https://www.globalsign.com/repository/
```

That policy OID corresponds to the EV OID for GlobalSign.

Then, if you visit http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.1.1, it's described as

> {iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprise(1) 4146 certificate-policies(1) **extended-Validation-SSL**(1)}

Comment: Alright. Thanks for that answer. However I tried that for example with the GlobalSign certificate (https://www.globalsign.com/) and their policy identifier does not show up on the wiki site. Maybe it is sufficient to grab the OIDs from the chromium source code (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/cert/ev_root_ca_metadata.cc).

Comment: An OID is a unique publicly-registered ID, therefore the OID database is public, for example, here's a site that will look up an OID for you: http://www.oid-info.com/

Comment: Also is the field for the OID standardised or is it just somewhere in the certificate?

Comment: Excellent answer. With current openssl version (>= 1.1.1) instead of running `openssl x509 -noout -text -in xxx.pem` and manually searching through the output, you can run `openssl x509 -noout -ext certificatePolicies -in xxx.pem` to show only the certificate policies.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Extended Validation certificate identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Removal_of_special_UI_indicators) from Wikipedia:

> EV certificates are standard X.509 digital certificates. The primary way to identify an EV certificate is by referencing the *Certificate Policies* extension field.
>
> Each issuer uses a different *object identifier* (OID) in this field to identify their EV certificates, and each OID is documented in the issuer's *Certification Practice Statement*.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.globalsign.com:443 2>1 | \
> openssl x509 -noout -ext certificatePolicies
X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
    Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.1.1
      CPS: https://www.globalsign.com/repository/
    Policy: 2.23.140.1.1
^C (interrupt)
```

In this example, the CP extension contains three *qualifiers*.

- The *Policy* value of `1.3.6.1.4.1.4146.1.1`, a GlobalSign ***legacy*** CP (OID), and the *Policy* value of `2.23.140.1.1`, a CA/Browser Forum OID, both indicate that the certificate complies with an EV policy.
- The *CPS* qualifier gives a pointer to the URI where the particular applicable CPS for the policy may be found.

Here is an another example about DigiCert:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.digicert.com:443 2>1 | \
> openssl x509 -noout -ext certificatePolicies
X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
    Policy: 2.16.840.1.114412.2.1
    Policy: 2.23.140.1.1
      CPS: http://www.digicert.com/CPS
^C (interrupt)
```

References:

- [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate
- [2]: https://cabforum.org/object-registry/
- [3]: https://www.globalsign.com/en/repository/GlobalSign_CP_v6.6_final.pdf
- [4]]: https://www.digicert.com/content/dam/digicert/pdfs/legal/DigiCert-CPS-V.5.6.pdf